# Ford Figo Door light on when all doors are closed

Tags: electrical, ford, troubleshooting, door, computer

I have a Ford Figo 2012, the last few weeks the door light on the dashboard has been on even through, all the doors are closed. (The light only comes on when I start my engine, as expected with Figo's)

I did a quick search on the internet, and saw that its possible that the switch inside the lock of the door could be stuck, due to dirt.  I sprayed electrical lubricant into each lock, and then open and closed the doors a few times each, but no change.

This has happen 3 times already.  First time after I left my car in the hot sun for a few hours, but it sorted itself out, after a long trip to the city.  A week later, I again left it out in the hot sun, but I took it in to get looked at by a Ford Dealer.  They replace the plug that connects to the lock, by the drivers door, that work.  Yet again a week later I left my car in the hot sun. I just notices that temperature may have a part to play here.

I took it back to the dealer today, the technician is having trouble working out what is wrong.  He told me He replaced the GEM module with a new Figo's one, he reset the computer, cleared all IDC codes. Still nothing changes.  He went father to explain that for some reason it seem the computer cannot talk to the GEM.

What I also notices; if I switch the left indicator on (left blinker) the door light flashes, and chimes at me.  But not the same for right.  Maybe its some form of troubleshooting mechanism.

Anyone idea how to solve this problem or where to look, or check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instrument panel is part of the ECU on your vehicle, electrically. If the GEM has been substituted and still the problem has remained, a critical look at the instrument panel is required. Moisture or dampness, even a water entry from the windscreen, could cause corrosion to the IP and cause mis-function. Fords had this problem with European Focus's.

Comment: I have forward this to the technician, they still cannot see anything wrong.  They gonna keep working on it, but this may be a clue.

Comment: The auto tech, said that they had to replace the whole cluster in my Figo. Changes that moisture was the cause of the problem.